# JSF ajax renders inputText but not panelGrid

Tags: ajax, jsf, rendering, panelgrid

I found a strange behaviour regarding the ajax rendering of JSF and I am not shure what I am missing.
For simplicity I have a page with an `h:inputText` and and a `h:panelGrid` with a button inside. When someone clicks the button, the value of the `h:inputText` should be set with a standard value and the `h:panelGrid` should disappear. At first I will show the code then I explain it a bit more.

**xhtml page:**

```
<h:inputText id="trackingIdValue" value="#{bean.trackingId}" />

<h:panelGrid border="15"  id="panel"  rendered="#{not empty bean.list}">
    <h:commandButton action="#{bean.render}" value="Clear Panel" >
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="panel trackingIdValue" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGrid>
```

**corresponding bean:**

```
private Long trackingId;
private List<String> list;

public Long getTrackingId() {
    return trackingId;
}

public List<String> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList( List<String> list ) {
     this.list = list;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
     // the list will be filled with some initial values
}

public void render() {
     this.trackingId = 954643L;
     list.clear();
}
```

When the page gets loaded the list will be filled with some values in the `PostConstruct`. This leads to the displaying of the panel because the list is not empty now. But when I click the button in the panel (where I change the trackingId and empty the list) the trackingId changed in the GUI but the panel is still visible. What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

As written in the comment I tried the code above in an empty project and there it works. I currently have a qiete huge application so shrinked down my pages and ended the following:

My project is consists of multiple page templates.In my master layout I have a `h:head` tag which loads many of my stylesheets I need for the application. When I completely remove the `h:head` tag then it works but then of course my styling is pretty bad. What does this has to do with my ajax loading and the panelgrid?

**UPDATE 2**

I have shorten my application to just one tiny page:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="masterStyle.css" library="css"  />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="trackingIdValue" value="#{testBean.trackingId}" />
        <h:panelGroup border="15" id="panel"
            rendered="#{not empty testBean.list}">
            <h:commandButton action="#{testBean.render}" value="Clear Panel">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" render="panel trackingIdValue" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

When I remove the header tag the ajax request works fine with both the inputtext and the panel. But when I add my stylesheets in the header like above ajax only works with the inputtext.

Comment: Which is your bean's scope?

Comment: The bean is in view scope, but because of the ajax rendering, this should not be the problem I think

Comment: Check out the `getList` method that return a completely empty list after hitting the button

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I am clearing the list inside the render method and when I print out the size of the list after the render method is finished, it tells me that size is zero

Comment: Mmh, that's strange. Anyway, would you mind using the `rendered` attribute in the wrapped `h:commandButton` instead of the `panelGrid` to be rendered? It's a best practice in JSF to do like that.

Comment: Unfortunately not because thats exactly what I am trying to reach. At the end the panel contains a datatable and when there are no elements in the list anymore not only the datatable should disappear but also the panel (because of styling)

Comment: Then why not wrap everything with `h:panelGroup` or `ui:fragment` and render the whole thing?

Comment: I also tryied a panelgroup but it did not work. But I tested the whole thing on an empty project and there it works. I have a qiete huge project now so this is hard to complain. I will try to shrink it down and try it again

Comment: I found the problem but it is still very strange. I will edit my posting.

Comment: I have updated the question, maybe you can help me with this.

Comment: What happens when putting your `h:outputStyleSheet` in the `h:body`? It should work properly. In fact I think it's a best practice for JSF.

Comment: When I put the `h:outputStyleSheet` in the `h:body` the scrips will not be loaded anymore